# Licensing for ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, license, pricing

I need help on buying 1 x ArcGIS 10 for Server licenses for a production environment. We have three servers with below configurations:

1. **Server 1** - 8 core, 24GB, 64-bit OS, Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise
2. **Server 2** - 8 core, 24GB, 64-bit OS, Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise
3. **Server 3** - Database server - Linux OS - Oracle 10g - 64 bit with ArcSDE 10

Our plan is to use Server 1 as a main server, where SOM and SOC will be installed and Server 2 as load balancing server (i.e only SOC will be installed).

Our application consumes 1 map service (with 80 layers) and 2 GP services (50 tools for various GIS operation) and 1 Geometry service. *NO EDITING FUNCTIONALITY*. Lot of saving in SDE database will be done with other business requirements. Roughly 40 concurrent users at the maximum in any given point of time.

We also use some standard ArcGIS GP Tools like the Aggregate Tool, which warrants an enterprise edition of ArcGIS server.

Can you please explain how an ArcGIS Server License (Enterprise Advanced) needs to be procured?

I am looking for optimized licensing for this setup.

Comment: I would recommend actually calling ESRI to get details on this. They will be able to tell you how many cores per license, costs, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly says that "We are not a formal GIS Software Support Site and are likely to close questions and recommend you seek official routes for support if you ... ask about licensing, pricing and/or release dates"

Answer (score 2):

The license depends on the number of cores. If you buy an enterprise license then you can use 'n' number of cores. Each SOC machine will require an additional license (As per ESRI standard for US. I'm not sure for other countries)

Please check [functionality matrix for more details](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf).

Comment: @sunil- I am looking for ArcGIS server 10 (not 10.1) and servers are in US. I learnt that 1 license will cater 4 cores, if server has 8 cores then 2 license required. I want to confirm though.

Comment: @iamlaksh1..According to your requirement you need to contact esri US representative he/she will tell you the cost and other things..I confirmed this from Esri Support.thanks